# my two select tag is in php loop 1 for weight of product another is price of product. I want ,whenever unit is changed, price will auto changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 while($val1=mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
{
<select id="units" name="unit">
       <?php 
            for($i=0;$i<count($subwt);$i++)
            {
                    $unit=$subwt[$i];
                    $myprice=$sprice[$i];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $unit; ?>"><?php echo $unit; ?> </option>
      <?php } ?>
 </select>

    <select id="prices" name="price" style="display:none;" >
    <?php 
            for($i=0;$i<count($sprice);$i++)
            {
                  $myprice=$sprice[$i];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $myprice; ?>"><?php echo $myprice; ?> </option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#units").change(function () {
            var val1=document.getElementById("units").selectedIndex;
            document.getElementById("prices").selectedIndex=val1;
            document.getElementById("oprices").selectedIndex=val1;
            document.getElementById("un").innerHTML=document.getElementById("prices").value;
            document.getElementById("unt").value=document.getElementById("units").value;
            document.getElementById("shprice").value=document.getElementById("prices").value;
            });
            });
</script>
<form name="f1" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="shprice" name="shprice" value="<?php echo $sprice[0]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="unt" name="unt" value="<?php echo $subwt[0]; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="addtocart" value="Add To Cart" class="button">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

this code doesn't work for me. I want to make, when select box of unit is set to specific option index then price index automatically set to same option index using javascript or jquery or ajax or any.. plz help me to solve this problem
please help me to find out mistake and give me solution.

Comment: You appear to be re-using the same `id` value in your HTML.  When there's more than one element with `id="units"` then the selector `$("#units")` is going to fail.

Comment: would you give me its solution?